# Highcharts - how to display a chart with stacked and un-stacked columns side-by-side

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to display both stacked and unstacked columns side-by-side in a Highcharts chart? I understand you can manipulate the series.stack() method and pass in a String but unable to get it right.

Similar to `enter code here`[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/stack/) but with both stacked and unstacked columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give a different, unique ID (could be a number) and there will be no stack - just a column.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s63ae9d2/

```
series: [
    {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0],
        stack: 0
    }, {
        data: [30, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
        stack: 0
    }, {
        data: [106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 29.9, 71.5],
        stack: 1
    }, {
        data: [148.5, 216.4, 30, 176.0, 135.6],
        stack: 2
    }
]
```